# Testing Apache Camel with TestNG being enabled with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, testng

I have created an Apache Camel project using Spring Boot where I configure the routes in a @Component annotated class.

```
@Component
public final class EdlRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public final void configure() throws Exception {
      //here is the setup of my Camel routes 
      ...
    }
}
```

Additionally I have a test class which extends AbstractCamelTestNGSpringContextTests containing one test method for testing my route. 
Within the test class I need to start the CamelContext manually as I need to startup an embedded FTP server prior to testing.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = EdlApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisableJmx(false)
@UseAdviceWith
@MockEndpoints("*")
@ContextConfiguration(classes=EdlRouteBuilder.class)
public class RouteTest extends AbstractCamelTestNGSpringContextTests {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteTest.class);

  @Autowired
  private CamelContext camelContext;

  ...

  @BeforeClass
  public final void beforeClass() throws Exception {
  private FtpServer ftpServer;
     ...
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public final void beforeClass() throws Exception {
    ...
  }
}
```

Problem is that the CamelContext is not autowired but I get the following excetption:

```
15:56:15.438 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6ce139a4] to prepare test instance [com.rwetrading.integration.camel.mft.edl.RouteTest@7ee955a8]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.rwetrading.integration.camel.mft.edl.RouteTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'camelContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.apache.camel.CamelContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:367)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:400)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
        at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:165)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:147)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.apache.camel.CamelContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:578)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
15:56:15.485 [main] INFO com.rwetrading.integration.camel.mft.edl.RouteTest - ********************************************************************************
15:56:15.485 [main] INFO com.rwetrading.integration.camel.mft.edl.RouteTest - Testing done: test(com.rwetrading.integration.camel.mft.edl.RouteTest)
15:56:15.487 [main] INFO com.rwetrading.integration.camel.mft.edl.RouteTest - Took: 0.001 seconds (1 millis)
15:56:15.487 [main] INFO com.rwetrading.integration.camel.mft.edl.RouteTest - ********************************************************************************
```

Comment: camel-testng is deprecated - I suggest to use JUnit with camel-test.

Comment: For the record, related discussion on the TestNG mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/testng-users/TeBzN-z0Q4g/sZjjcGs3CQAJ